# Can you extend a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I help maintain a JavaScript library that produces spy functions which allow you to inspect how a passed-in function was called (mainly for use in unit testing).

The library creates a function that has additional properties on it that allow you to inspect the calls.

Is it possible to create a TypeScript definition that will allow the function to be passed in to methods that require a function AND have extra properties?

This is invalid, but something like:

```
class Spy extends function {
    wasCalled: () => boolean;
    ...
}
```

Which would allow me to pass a spy into a function with this signature:

```
function subjectUnderTest(callback:() => void) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, [the TypeScript handbook calls this a "hybrid type"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types), because it's a combination of a function type and a regular interface.

```
interface Spy {
    (foo: string, bar: number) : boolean; // Just an example
    wasCalled() : boolean;
}

var spy : Spy = createASpySomehow();
var result = spy("foo", 123);
if (spy.wasCalled()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps because it is a partial answer as `createASpySomehow()` hints at. How can we create an instance of the interface Spy **by extending a function**? The Typescript documentation linked in the answer uses a different approach: cast the function to the interface then add properties to the function, see my answer for an example. However even my answer doesn't extend a function.

Comment: @nalply The original question was about writing a TypeScript type definition for an existing JavaScript library. Sure, if you're writing the library *implementation* in TypeScript as well, then you'll need an explicit cast where you create the function. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to extend a class with a function, too, and worked out a TypeScript-only solution. I am not really sure whether this is a good idea because clever solutions are not always good solutions. YMMV.

Thanks to Mattias Buelens to provide a partial answer! I am building on it.

```
// same as in the answer of Mattias
interface Spy {
    (foo: string, bar: number): boolean // Just an example
    wasCalled(): boolean
}

// and now for the real solution!
class Spy {
    _wasCalled: boolean
    _baz: boolean // Just an example

    private constructor(baz: boolean) {
        this._wasCalled = false
        this._baz = baz
    }

    wasCalled(): boolean {
        return this._wasCalled
    }

    toString() { return '[object Spy]' }

    static create(baz: boolean) {
        const f = <Spy>function(this: Spy, foo: string, bar: number): boolean {
            // Do your thing here. Use f instead of this!
            console.log('wasCalled', f.wasCalled())
            f._wasCalled = true
        }
        const spy = new Spy(baz)
        Object.assign(f, spy)
        Object.setPrototypeOf(f, Spy.prototype)

        return f
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a function and the instance of `Spy`, then assign both the prototype and the properties to the function. Return the instance from a static method. A bonus is the `toString()` method.

```
const spy = Spy.create(true)
console.log('calling spy', spy('foo', 42))
console.log('instanceof', spy instanceof Spy)
```

works as expected.

I don't think that `new Spy()` would work because we need to assign to a function not the other way round. And because we can't replace `this` we can't make `this` a callable. A hypothetical way I see is to extend a class with really a function constructor somehow like this: `class Spy2 extends function() {} {}`, but I didn't find a way to get this working.

Comment: Interesting solution, but perhaps a little bit too much magic. For example: since you replace the function's prototype with `Spy.prototype`, you lose methods like `spy.bind()`, `spy.apply()` or `spy.call()`. I think it's easier to just add the extra methods directly on the function, instead of trying to put them on the function's prototype.

Comment: I agree... One advantage of this solution is that you can have a complicated constructor and that you'll get TypeScript's type verification during that.