# (TypeScript) Extending KnockoutObservableArray

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, extends

I want to make a TypeScript class that is loosely `MyKOArray<T> extends KnockoutObservableArray<T>`.  Is this even possible?  If so, is there a compact way to do it?

- I read Knockout's [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) section, but it doesn't seem applicable as I'm trying to (among other things) add a `state` attribute -- not affect the existing subscribable.
- I could list the things I've tried and the ways they've gone wrong (e.g. TS2507, TS2322, etc.) but I doubt they'd be informative.  As a baseline, I believe some of the essential details are:

  - `KnockoutObservableArray` is an interface so I really need to "extend" `ko.observableArray` (the "factory" function).
  - The signature of `ko.observableArray` is not right (i.e. no `new` and it handles the initial value in the function rather than a `constructor` method).
  - I could `return ko.observableArray(initial)` from a constructor, but have not been able to get the prototype chain right (e.g. methods not available).
  - I could [override `@@create`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/should-the-default-constructor-return-the-return-value-of-super) in JS to `return ko.observableArray(initial)`, but I've had trouble finding a JS example (let alone a valid TS implementation).
- I also found an [extremely old discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/4gjTuzMLixI/discussion) on a similar topic.  The conclusion there was that it was impossible due to a lack of prototyping in KO, but the current source code (e.g. `ko.utils.setPrototypeOfOrExtend`) suggests that this conclusion may be out-of-date.
- I've also dug through plenty of generic TS extends questions (e.g. [Can you extend a function in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338013/can-you-extend-a-function-in-typescript)) without finding something that seemed to match.

===

EDIT:  Why?

I'm attempting to decouple my system using the following pattern (only documenting the "interesting case"):

- ViewModel makes a request to a data service (indirectly via a factory method on a class).  The data service returns an instance immediately (`MyClass` or `KnockoutObservableArray<MyClass>` for a Singleton or Collection respectively).
- Asynchronously, the service loads/populates (and manages real-time updates to) the returned instance.  This requires a subscription to a WebSocket for events and REST call(s) to load data (incl. the potential for retries).
- The service passes its progress to the instance by calling methods on the instance (the "callback" and "errback" in my pattern).
- These methods update a `state` attribute (i.e. observable) and may update something else (e.g. populate its values or populate an error message observable).
- The UI interrogates the `state` observable to communicate the state of loading (and other activities) to the user.

This is working great on my single instances.  The `state` method is interrogated (and updated) widely to ensure valid actions.

I'd like to duplicate the pattern on my KOArrays.  That way, I can discriminate between an empty array that is not-yet-loaded and a loaded array that happens to be empty.  I can also add a `state` and `error_message` to the KOArray to mirror the behavior of my instances.

Comment: Could you please add a short description about why exactly do you need this? It doesn't sound like a reasonable pattern in most of the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it's not possible the way you described.

#### Longer story

Knockout is not implemented in an object-oriented way. So basically almost everything it exposes are functions or plain objects, etc. The prototype handling is used there to *extend* the function instance which is returned by for example `ko.observable`. So basically *inheriting* from any kinds of Knockout stuff is not possible in an OOP sense.

If you need the inheritance to add functionality, you can add your new methods to `ko.observableArray.fn` object. Then this function will be callable on all `observableArray` instances afterwards. A quick example is here.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.hasElements = function() {
  return this().length > 0;
}
...
if (myModel.selectedItems.hasElements()) {
  ...
}
```

If you need the inheritance to restrict somethings, you can add your own factory function like this for example.

```
ko.myRestrictedObservableArray = function(initialValue) {
  if (!initialValue || !initialValue.length) {
    throw new "You can create an observable array only with a non-empty initial value";
  }

  return ko.observableArray(initialValue);
}
```

You can even *override* the original function if you wish so for example like this. Although, this is not a good practice in most cases.

```
var _original = ko.observableArray;
ko.observableArray = function(initialValue) {
  // ... do your custom things
  var array = _original.call(this, initialValue);
  // ... do your custom things 
  return array;
}
```

If you have yet another requirement, please describe it in more detail in you question.

Comment: In case you don't get an update, I edited the question to add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Zoltan's feedback, I ended up going with the following.  I'm sure there are bugs and opportunities to optimize, but it let me write everything in a Typescript class (with appropriate type checking in both directions):

In pure JS (e.g. a `<script>` in the HTML file or separate JS file):

```
function RestCollection(initialValue) {
    const fn = ko.observableArray(initialValue);
    // Static properties
    ko.utils.extend(fn.constructor, RestCollectionMixin);
    // Methods (already constructed so must attach directly, not to prototype)
    const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(RestCollectionMixin.prototype);
    for (let i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
        if (methods[i] == "constructor") continue;  // don't move over the constructor
        fn[methods[i]] = RestCollectionMixin.prototype[methods[i]].bind(fn)
    }
    // Constructed properties
    ko.utils.extend(fn, new RestCollectionMixin());
    return fn;
} {}

// RestCollectionMixin needs this; don't return or it will break the constructor
function KnockoutObservableArrayClass() {}
```

In a TS file:

```
// abstract is not passed to JS so this prevents misuse without breaking the RestCollection constructor
abstract class RestCollectionMixin<T> extends KnockoutObservableArrayClass<T> { // extends handles parent method access
    static FSM = class {
        static STATE_INIT = 'initializing';
        static STATE_READY = 'ready';
        static STATE_SAVING = 'save_requested';
        static STATE_DELETING = 'delete_requested';
        static STATE_DELETED = 'deleted';
        static STATE_ERROR = 'error';
    };
    public states() { // convenience accessor
        return this.constructor.FSM
    }
    public state:KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable(this.states().STATE_INIT);

    public processRestError(results) {
        this.state(this.states().STATE_ERROR)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, a definition file for `RestCollection` and `KnockoutObservableArrayClass` so TS checking works:

```
// provide KnockoutObservableArray properties and methods to the Mixin
interface KnockoutObservableArrayClass<T> extends KnockoutObservableArray<T> {
    new<T>(initialValue): KnockoutObservableArray<T>
}
declare const KnockoutObservableArrayClass:KnockoutObservableArrayClass<any>;

// Define the focal class, capturing all extensions in RestCollectionMixin
interface RestCollection<T> extends RestCollectionMixin<T> {
    new<T>(initialValue): RestCollection<T>
}
declare const RestCollection:RestCollection<any>;
```